# Can I use any other parameters besides CurrentCulture to select a C# resource file?

Tags: c#, localization, resx

As you probably know .NET selects resource files in a solution based on the .resx filename and the CurrentCulture setting. Meaning that if I have 3 resource files (say Resource.resx, Resource.fr-FR.resx and Resource.nl-NL.resx), I can select the French resources by simply changing the CurrentCulture to "fr-FR" in my app.config. The code that gets the string from the resource file does not have to be changed.

For my current project I'm exploring ways to switch strings in a similar way to how this works, but based on a parameter of my choosing. Say I have Resource.resx, Resource.Bar.resx and Resource.Fu.resx: can I automatically select a resource by changing a custom setting that is not the CurrentCulture, or would I have to build my own ResourceManager extension?

Or could I just set the CurrentCulture to "Fu"? I imagine this would clash with other built-in .NET functions.

Comment: It is technically possible to create a custom culture name.  But what could possibly be the point when you can simply use SomethingElse.resx and avoid a ton of other problems.

Comment: I'm using resource files to catalog DOM selectors for a UI-testing solution (using Selenium) we're using to test a rather large Model driven design-application. Since the application is a closed box that generates everything based on an internally configured Model, the selectors are subject to change between major releases. So a part of the testing solution might suddenly fail just because an id was changed. 


I'd like to keep all the selectors cataloged in a comprehensible way, where I'd just have to add a new *.branchX.resx file every time a new major branch is opened.